# Erro ao trazer os valores dentro de um objeto com uma array dentro

Tags: javascript

Preciso trazer os **valores do objeto** da minha API Json para os campos dentro de uma div de produtos que eu quero criar, estava dando tudo certo, até precisar **colocar os valores que estão dentro dos objetos dentro da div**. 
O que acontece é que ele não encontra o caminho dentro do objeto quando a função se inicia. 
Acho que o problema, são os arrays dentro do objeto. 
Penso que o caminho deveria ser **Objeto.NomeDoArray.NomeDoItemDentroDoArray**
Mas ele sempre retorna erro na primeira leitura de linha de caminho que aparece.

Segue o código:

```js
window.onload = async()=>{ 

    console.log('AQUI DEVE APARECER UM OBJETO JSON')

    const criaDiv = document.createElement('div')
    criaDiv.classList.add('produto')

    const areaDiv = document.querySelector('secaoProdutos')

    try{
        const produto = await fetch('https://frontend-intern-challenge-api.iurykrieger.now.sh/products?page=1')
        const resultado = await produto.json()
        console.log(resultado)
    }
    catch{
        conole.log("Não foi possivel excutar essa ação!")
    }
    
    const imagem = resultado.products.image //O ERRO ACONTECE AQUI <----------
    const nome = resultado.products.name
    const descricao = resultado.products.description
    const oldPrice = resultado.products.oldPrice
    const count= resultado.products.installments.count
    const value = resultado.products.installments.value

    console.log(imagem)
    console.log(nome)
    console.log(descricao)
    console.log(oldPrice)
    console.log(count)
    console.log(value)


    areaDiv.innerHTML =
    `
    <img src="${resultado.products.image}">
    <br>
    <h3 >${resultado.products.name}</h3>
    <br>
    <p>${resultado.products.description}</p>
    <br>
    <p>De: ${resultado.products.oldPrice}</p>
    <br>
    <h2>Por: ${resultado.products.price}</h2>
    <br>
    <p>ou ${resultado.products.installments.count}x ${resultado.products.installments.value}</p>
    `
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="PT-BR">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ProjetoPhToco</title>

    <!--Reset.CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css/reset.css">
    <!------------->
    <!--Cabeçalho-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css/cabecalho.css">
    <!------------->
    <!--Corpo do Site-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css/corpo.css">
    <!-------------->

</head>
<header>
    <div class="cabecalhoCorpo">

        <div class="textosCabecalho">
            <h1 class="h1Cabecalho">uma seleção de produtos</h1>
            <h2 class="h2Cabecalho">especial para você</h2>
            <h3 class="h3Cabecalho">Todos os produtos desta lista foram selecionados a partir da sua navegação.
                Aproveite!</h3>
        </div>
        <nav class="navMenu">
            <input class="botaoMenu" type="button" value="Coneça a Lix">
            <input class="botaoMenu" type="button" value="Ajude o algoritimo">
            <input class="botaoMenu" type="button" value="Seus Produtos">
            <input class="botaoMenu" type="button" value="Compartilhe">
        </nav>

    </div>
</header>

<body>

</body>

<h2 class="h2Corpo">Sua seleção especial</h2>
<div class="secaoProdutos">
    <div class="produto">
        <img class="imgProduto" src="img/cocacola.jpg" alt="imagem de uma cocacola" >
        <br>
        <h3 class="nomeProduto">Nome do produto</h3>
        <br>
        <p class="descricaoProduto">Descrição do produto um pouco maior, com duas linhas ou três que explica melhor do que se trata.</p>
        <br>
        <p class="deProduto">De: R$23,99</p>
        <br>
        <h2 class="porProduto">Por: R$19,99</h2>
        <br>
        <p class="ouProduto">ou 2x de R$9,99</p>
    </div>
        <div class="produto">
            <img class="imgProduto" src="img/cocacola.jpg" alt="imagem de uma cocacola" >
            <br>
            <h3 class="nomeProduto">Nome do produto</h3>
            <br>
            <p class="descricaoProduto">Descrição do produto um pouco maior, com duas linhas ou três que explica melhor do que se trata.</p>
            <br>
            <p class="deProduto">De: R$23,99</p>
            <br>
            <h2 class="porProduto">Por: R$19,99</h2>
            <br>
            <p class="ouProduto">ou 2x de R$9,99</p>
        </div>

        <div class="produto">
            <img class="imgProduto" src="img/cocacola.jpg" alt="imagem de uma cocacola" >
            <br>
            <h3 class="nomeProduto">Nome do produto</h3>
            <br>
            <p class="descricaoProduto">Descrição do produto um pouco maior, com duas linhas ou três que explica melhor do que se trata.</p>
            <br>
            <p class="deProduto">De: R$23,99</p>
            <br>
            <h2 class="porProduto">Por: R$19,99</h2>
            <br>
            <p class="ouProduto">ou 2x de R$9,99</p>
        </div>

        <div class="produto">
            <img class="imgProduto" src="img/cocacola.jpg" alt="imagem de uma cocacola" >
            <br>
            <h3 class="nomeProduto">Nome do produto</h3>
            <br>
            <p class="descricaoProduto">Descrição do produto um pouco maior, com duas linhas ou três que explica melhor do que se trata.</p>
            <br>
            <p class="deProduto">De: R$23,99</p>
            <br>
            <h2 class="porProduto">Por: R$19,99</h2>
            <br>
            <p class="ouProduto">ou 2x de R$9,99</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>

    </footer>

    <script src="javaScript/sync.js"></script>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vários erros no teu código...

1- `const areaDiv = document.querySelector('secaoProdutos')` falta-lhe o `.` para indicar o seletor de classe

2- Usar `const`, ou `let` dentro de um `try{}` vai fechar essa variável dentro desse bloco, não permitindo aceder à mesma fora dele. Deves usar `let` fora do `try` e depois sobreescrever a variável.

3- o teu json tem uma array dentro de `produtos`, o que implica que tens de iterar essa array para aceder a cada produto

4- para adicionar esse HTML ao DOM tens de criar `<div class="produto">` para cada um dos elementos dessa array e depois de ter o seu HTML tens de adicionar (`appendChild`) ao elemento pai, ou seja: `.secaoProdutos`.

5- no teu `catch` tens um erro na palavra `console`...

Correções feitas, creio que é isto que queres:

```js
window.onload = async() => {

  console.log('AQUI DEVE APARECER UM OBJETO JSON')

  const criaDiv = document.createElement('div')
  criaDiv.classList.add('produto')

  const areaDiv = document.querySelector('.secaoProdutos')
  let products = [];
  try {
    const produto = await fetch('https://frontend-intern-challenge-api.iurykrieger.now.sh/products?page=1')
    const resultado = await produto.json();
    products = resultado.products
  } catch {
    console.log("Não foi possivel excutar essa ação!")
  }
  
  products.forEach(produto => {
    const divProduto = document.createElement('div');
    divProduto.className = 'produto';
    divProduto.innerHTML =
      `
    <img src="http:${produto.image}">
    <br>
    <h3 >${produto.name}</h3>
    <br>
    <p>${produto.description}</p>
    <br>
    <p>De: ${produto.oldPrice}</p>
    <br>
    <h2>Por: ${produto.price}</h2>
    <br>
    <p>ou 
    ${produto.installments.count}x 
    ${produto.installments.value}
    </p>
    `;
    areaDiv.appendChild(divProduto);
  });



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="PT-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ProjetoPhToco</title>

  <!--Reset.CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css/reset.css">
  <!------------->
  <!--Cabeçalho-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css/cabecalho.css">
  <!------------->
  <!--Corpo do Site-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css/corpo.css">
  <!-------------->

</head>
<header>
  <div class="cabecalhoCorpo">

    <div class="textosCabecalho">
      <h1 class="h1Cabecalho">uma seleção de produtos</h1>
      <h2 class="h2Cabecalho">especial para você</h2>
      <h3 class="h3Cabecalho">Todos os produtos desta lista foram selecionados a partir da sua navegação. Aproveite!
      </h3>
    </div>
    <nav class="navMenu">
      <input class="botaoMenu" type="button" value="Coneça a Lix">
      <input class="botaoMenu" type="button" value="Ajude o algoritimo">
      <input class="botaoMenu" type="button" value="Seus Produtos">
      <input class="botaoMenu" type="button" value="Compartilhe">
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>

<body>

</body>

<h2 class="h2Corpo">Sua seleção especial</h2>
<div class="secaoProdutos">
 </div>

<footer>
</footer>

<script src="javaScript/sync.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu muito certo, realmente, não me lembrava de criar a let ou do forEch.  Sem querer abusar de sua ajuda, mas fiquei com mais uma dúvida. Quase todas as informações foram puxadas e inseridas na página, somente as imagens que não foram trazidas, ficaram quebradas. O Senhor sabe me dizer o motivo? Ai clicar no caminho dentro do objeto, ele redireciona sem problemas para a imagem no navegar.

Comment: @BrunoMartins os dados nessa array faltam `http(s)` no url das imagens... vem só com `//`. Adicionei `http` no código, muda para  `https` se for o caso.